# How to exclude "commit" field from rails post payload?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, oauth

I am POSTing data to a very finnicky OAuth 1.0 external endpoint that cannot have any except very specific fields in the payload

I want to expose this endpoint to the user via a button click -- so i currently have the fields setup in a form (using `form_tag`) but I also have a `submit_tag` inside the form to allow the user to click it and perform the POST.

Unfortunately the existence of this `submit_tag` generates an input field of type `<input name="commit" type="submit" value="Claim">` and this ends up inside the payload as `commit=Claim`, this breaks the endpoint.

Is there any way of using a form in rails to POST data to an external endpoint WITHOUT including the `commit=Claim` field (which exists are a result of the button for submitting the form) ?

If not, what's the best way to do this? Unfortunately I can't post behind the scenes, as it performs a redirect that I need the user to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to get rid of the `name` attribute of your input button. Try this:

```
submit_tag "Claim", name: ""
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant thanks! I was stuck on this issue for a very long time! :)